# My Snapshot views in ClearCase have disappeared, how can I get them back?

Tags: view, clearcase, snapshot

I have 3 views on my machine, I can see the structure on the windows directory but now when I open ClearCase I cannot see any of them on the ClearCase Navigator...how can I add them?

Answer (score 4):

The cleanest solution:

Go at the root directory of one of those views in a shell session (DOS or bash or...)
type:

```
clearexplorer .
```

<sup>(Note the final space followed by a dot '`.`')</sup>

That will open the ClearCase Explorer directly in the current path, and will restore the right shortcut.

---

The "less-clean" solution:

Open the ClearCase Explorer, and ask for a "refresh view shortcuts" <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd>.

If your identity hasn't changed, it will restore the shortcuts of all *your* views in the ClearCase Explorer.

---

If that doesn't work:

- check the properties from one of your views:

```
cd /path/to/root/of/one/of/your/views
cleartool lsview -l -full -pro -cview
```

- compare that with your credentials (how you are known both locally and on your Vob server)

```
credmap VobServerName
```

(you need to add `etc/utils` from ClearCase to your path)

Comment: 'Less Clean' solution worked for me.  Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problems. Normally, this problem happens if Windows couldn't contact the clearcase server at startup and the ALBD service would stop automatically.

For Windows environment, check if albd service is running from clearcase item in control panel. If so, stop it and then start clearcase 
then refresh with shortcut (Alt+F5) from  the clearcase explorer, 
or simply restart Windows