# Checkout issue from Windows ClearCase client

Tags: version-control, clearcase, cleartool

A user cannot checkout from windows client ClearCase ( see picture)

And yet, the same user can checkout from a unix client.

[image: Error message]

Why?

Thanks for your answer @VonC

Please find my below findings

Here the primary group of the vob is

```
/usr/atria/bin/cleartool desc vob:/vobs/MCT

versioned object base "/vobs/MCT"
  created 2010-03-03T16:42:52+02:00 by Admin.WTD (wtadmin.wtusers@frmrssucc004)
  "MSS Access"
  master replica: xh_mct_athens@/vobs/MCT
  replica name: xh_mct_athens
  VOB family feature level: 5
  modification by remote privileged user: allowed
  atomic checkin: disabled

  VOB ownership:
    owner *********servername***/ca_xhvadm
    group eelinnis.emea.nsn-net.net/ccusers_xhaul_athens

  ACLs enabled: No
  Attributes:
  FeatureLevel = 5
  Hyperlinks:
    AdminVOB -> vob:/vobs/MPTADMIN
```

And user id output is

```
id karageor
uid=61333334(karageor) gid=8003(ccusers_xhaul_athens) 
groups=7000(hostingusers_cic_athens),8003(ccusers_xhaul_athens)
```

and on the windows the primary group is set as

[image: Primary Group on Windows]

Is the unix group ccusers_xhaul_athens has to be set as windows primary group on system variable

Kindly confirm

Comment: Could you please reopen the question? This is crystal clear for me, but I was not there to answer. (Reminder: I have answered almost *all* ClearCase questions the past 10 years: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/clearcase/topusers)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main factor which explain a permission issue in a ClearCase interop (Windows ClearCase client - Linux ClearCase server) is the `CLEARCASE_PRIMARY_GROUP` environment variable.

That variable (`CLEARCASE_PRIMARY_GROUP`) needs to:

- be set to the primary group of the vob of the element the user is trying to checkout ([primary or secondary](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9276100/6309): type `cleartool describe -l vob:\YourVob` to list them)
- be the same value as the primary group of the Linux user (who can successfully checkout the same element in his/her Linux ClearCase view): type `id -a` to see that primary group `eelinnis.emea.nsn-net.net/ccusers_xhaul_athens`

Make sure on Windows the user is not launching the client with another account (Administrator, or System account), and the `CLEARCASE_PRIMARY_GROUP` is set.
(and the [number of group is not too high](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21486700/6309))

You can use the [`creds` utility](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21221403) to see your credentials.

See more at "[ClearCase won't allow Check-In](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3044756/6309)" and use the [`credmap` utility](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21670533) to verify the group assignments between Windows and Unix.

Type set CL in a CMD shell in Windows to see the actual full value of the `CLEARCASE_PRIMAY_GROUP` environment variable (`??_EE_CLEARCASE_USERS_XHAUL_ATHENS`)

You need to see if that group maps to the Linux one.

Check also the [protection associated to your view](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3131126/6309). See [`fix_prot` on Windows here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46478530/6309).

Comment: thanks for your answer, I've edited my question with more information, could you please help.